# How to capture the Name of a Table in a Database when running a stored procedure on multiple tables

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, stored-procedures

I am currently making a python program that will run a stored procedure which has multiple select statements for multiple different tables. I am storing the results in a dataframe and the displaying it with a treeview. I want to make it so that the user can see what table each row of the results came from. I was wondering if there is anyway that I could modify my stored procedure so that each row that is returned in the procedure also includes the table name.

Here is the stored procedure as of right now

```
procedure [dbo].[getUser](@username nvarchar(225))
AS
Select username,user_id,user_type
from db1.dublin_table
where username like '%' + TRIM(@username) + '%'
ORDER BY username

Select username,user_id,user_type
from db2.nyc_table
where username like '%' + TRIM(@username) + '%'
ORDER BY username

Select username,user_id,user_type
from db3.tokyo_table
where username like '%' + TRIM(@username) + '%'
ORDER BY username
```

I am somewhat new to SQL stored procedures so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try "select username, user_id, user_type, 'dublin_table' as source_table from db1.dublin_table...", do the same for all select statements.

Comment: Curious why you are using a wild card on username.    If @username='' you would get all data, or if @username='a' you would get all user with an A

Comment: @JohnCappelletti i am aware that it will bring back any username that contain the input as a substring

Comment: @DaleK probably a nicer way of phrasing that but ok. Taken care of!